# HttpWebRequest returns unreadable data

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am basically sending a HttpWebRequest to a website and having the resulting output displayed in a WebBrowser control using vb.net.

Example output:

[image: Example output]

The code works and sends the correct data. However, it is far from readable.
How do I make the html page readable?

```
Dim Logincookie As New CookieContainer

Try
            Logincookie = New CookieContainer

            Try
                'may have to send a request to load the easyweb webpage first to get the cookies


                Dim postData As String = "Personal information being sent to website url"
                Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
                Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

                Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("Website URL with personal information being sent"), HttpWebRequest)

                Dim myWebHeaderCollection As WebHeaderCollection = postReq.Headers
                myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Cache-Control: max-age=0")
                myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Origin: website subdomain")
                myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch")
                myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8")


                postReq.CookieContainer = Logincookie
                postReq.Method = "POST"
                postReq.Host = "website subdomain"
                postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"
                postReq.KeepAlive = True
                postReq.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
                postReq.Referer = "website URL I was coming from prior to the website I am now"
                postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

                Dim postReqStream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream
                postReqStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
                postReqStream.Close()

                Dim postResponse As HttpWebResponse
                postResponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                Logincookie.Add(postResponse.Cookies)



                Dim postreqReader As New StreamReader(postResponse.GetResponseStream())
                Dim thepage As String = postreqReader.ReadToEnd
                WebBrowser.DocumentText = thepage
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print("Unhandled exception logging in.")
                Debug.Print(ex.Message)
            End Try

Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print("Unhandled exception saving data.")
    Debug.Print(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: It looks like [.NET: Is it possible to get HttpWebRequest to automatically decompress gzip'd responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815721/net-is-it-possible-to-get-httpwebrequest-to-automatically-decompress-gzipd-re) may contain the information you need.