# decompress and decode http ( gzip and chunked ) response from SslStream c#

Tags: c#, http, encoding

I am using SslStream class for some reason and I can't use WebClient Class instead.

as title I have a response with :

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

when I am trying to read response normally it gives the response header then characters like this : 1297
?E?)ebM???X?kr

I tried to use GZipStream class :

```
    bytes = new Byte[256];
    data = null;
    i = 0;
    GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    while ((i = gz.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
        data += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(data);
```

But it gives exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException'
Additional information: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

I tried to read header bytes first and and when start to read the body it gives the same exception

Comment: Possible related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815721/net-is-it-possible-to-get-httpwebrequest-to-automatically-decompress-gzipd-re

Comment: I can't use WebRequest or WebClient , I need to work only with a SslStream